# conversion of dataframe into Matrix in R

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I was trying to convert a dataframe into a realRatingMatrix. But for that, I'm first converting the dataframe to a matrix and a matrix to a realRatingMatrix.
The dataframe *df* contains `475984 rows` and `3 columns`.
`Column1` is the `productID`, `column2` is the `customer names` and `column3` contains `rating of the product` given by the respective user
Steps followed:
1. Removal of missing values
2. Deduplication of data
3. Conversion of dataframe into a matrix
4. Testing the matrix

```
library(recommenderlab)
sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# 100 missing values in column2
df <- df[-which(is.na(df$col2) == TRUE), ]
sum(duplicated(df))
# 580 duplicates
df <- df[-which(duplicated(df) == TRUE), ]

# Converting the dataframe into realratingMatrix
df_matrix <- data.matrix(df)

# Testing matrix
str(df_matrix)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df_matrix)
```

While converting the dataframe into a matrix I'm getting the following warning message:
    **Warning message:
    In data.matrix(beer_data) : NAs introduced by coercion**
Now when I convert the created matrix to dataframe my customer names column (column2) has just 38 entries rest all are NAs.

Can someone please suggest some way to correct my code and get the desired output.

Comment: Can you provide some simulated or sample data?

Answer (score 0):

In R, a matrix is just a vector that is split up in certain places to form the rows and columns. Thus, all elements must be of the same type. In particular, if you have a data.frame with one column of numeric data, and one column of character data, you won't be able to convert it into a matrix. I don't know for sure, but it looks like column2 might be a character vector.

Note that I have no knowledge of the recommenderlab package.

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B"), col2 = 1:2, stringsAsFactors = F)

data.matrix(df)
#Warning message:
#In data.matrix(df) : NAs introduced by coercion

df
#     col1 col2
#[1,]   NA    1
#[2,]   NA    2
```